# Can we use a scope in react front end app to generate msal token for authentication, if that scope is not registered in Azure AD app registration?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am acquiring a token in react front-end app using msal-react library. To acquire a msal token, I am using a scope **api://client-id/AllowAnonymous** (e.g - api://GUID/AllowAnonymous) which is not registered in Azure AD App Registrations -> Expose an API -> Scopes.

In Azure AD App Registrations -> Expose an API -> Scopes, the registered scope is **http://domain-name/AllowAnonymous**.(e.g - http://example.com/AllowAnonymous)

[image]

I am able to authenticate using the token and even validation is passed.

**Is it correct/allowed to use a scope which is not registered in Azure AD Api permissions to generate a token?**

Comment: Are you getting an ID token or an access token? Or both?

Comment: I am getting an Access Token.

Comment: And does the access token contains a "scp" claim with "allowanonymous" as value? Can you show us the AAD App Registration API Permissions page for your frontend application? I would expect the http://example.com/allowanonymous scope there and when you request an access token, you have to specify a scope that is configured there...

Comment: Yes, I am getting "scp" claim as "allowanonymous" value as scope. **But my question is, can we use a scope which is not registered in AAD App Registration API Permissions, to generate a token?** I tried using the same, and I am able to acquire an Access Token and validate successfully using the same.